# Issue with Excel Sequence function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to learn using the `SEQUENCE` function in excel by using Microsoft documentation stated on this link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90

But when I replicate the same on the excel on my machine, it is showing as invalid. I am unable to comprehend where I am getting it wrong.

[image]

Comment: You likely don't have Excel 365

Comment: If you look at the link you provided, Microsoft lists the version where this formula works.  If your version is not on that list it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `=SEQUENCE(5)` this should return an array 1 - 5. If this doesn't work, you probably are using a version of Excel that does not offer the SEQUENCE function then try upgrading to Microsoft Office 365.

Microsoft Office 365 is a subscription based Microsoft Office Suite billed either per person or per organization. It provides regular updates to keep the office suite up to date.